# Showing information form from two tables

Tags: c#, wpf, database, entity-framework, listview

I'm writing a course selection program using WPF and Entity Framework 6. In my database I have three tables one for students who wish to select a course, one for the information about the courses (name of the course, start time, etc) and one for the information about the instructors. I have a section in my program that lists all the courses with the corresponding data about each of them but because the instructors exist in a different table I am not able to show them in my ListView in other word I have problem in joining data of two table and show them in a single ListView:

[image: here is an image from my database schema in entity framework]

and this is my code for showing the data of a course in a ListView which so far I'm unable to show the instructor due to the problem explained above

```
       private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var context = new Model1Container())
        {

            var course_List = new List<course>();
            foreach (var course in context.courses)
            {
                course_List.Add(course);
            }
            listView.ItemsSource = course_List;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What xaml did you try? The navigation properties are there, you should just have to use dot notation to get the instructor data. Debug and examine `course_list`, do instructors come in too?

Answer (score 0):

You have a one to many relationship between `Course` and `Instructor`, so, en `Course` entity you have a [navigation property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx) called `instructor` that you can use to show the related instructor.

Now my first suggestion is you don't need to iterate through all the courses to create a list, you can do this:

```
    using (var context = new Model1Container())
    {
        var course_List = context.courses.Include(c=>c.instructor).ToList();
        listView.ItemsSource = course_List;
    }
```

The [Include](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.113).aspx) extension method allows you include in your query the related object that you want to be included in your query result.

Now, to see the `Course` info and the related `Instructor` you could define a custom [ItemTemplate](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-data-binding-item-template/). As I said before, `instructor` is a `Course` property, so, you can do something like this.

```
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <WrapPanel>
             ...
             <TextBlock Text="Instructor: " />
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding instructor.name}" FontWeight="Bold" />
          </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: @SaeidGhafouri, If you don't include the `instructor` navigation property as part of your query, EF will throw an exception when you try to  check the instructor nav. property in any course in your list after your context instance die. So, to avoid that you need to include as part of your query that each course comes with the related instructor.

Comment: where exactly should I put the first (I mean the code not the xaml) statement you wrote? after my own code or within the previous answer, if so (within the previous answer) where exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is btter to have InsctruorId in course table, and use below code for joining tabes

```
        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (var context = new Model1Container())
            {

                var course_List = new List<course>();
                foreach (var course in GetAllCources)
                {
                    course_List.Add(course);
                }
                listView.ItemsSource = course_List;
            }
        }

        private List<course> GetAllCources()
        {
            return (from c in context.cources
             join i in context.instructors on c.instructorId equals c.Id
             select new
             {
                 Cources = c,
                 Instructors = i,
             }).AsEnumerable().Select(c =>  new Cources
             {
                 .
                 .
                 All required fields
                 .
                 .
                 .
             } : null).AsQueryable();
        }
```

You can use **Include** if do not want to select properties.

Comment: where should I exactly define the GetAllCourse? because by doing in the manner you wrote it here I get errors for the context which is said it's not defined and what exactly do you mean by "All the required fields"? I'm very new too this stuff sorry if my questions seems so stupid!